# PHP data extraction from .txt and sorting to kml

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

I'm  new to javascript and have very little knowledge of PHP. I'm trying to get the data from a google maps route formatted to a KML file. Right now I'm using *jquery stringify* to save the coördinates of points of the route to a textfile.

Textfile looks like this:

> [{"lat":51.101510000000005,"lng":4.948580000000001},{"lat":51.10208,"lng":4.94763},{"lat":51.102160000000005,"lng":4.94744},{"lat":51.102140000000006,"lng":4.944330000000001}]

What I would like to do is get the coördinates of each Lat and Lng and put them in a kml file.
Putting them into the file is probably something that I will be able to figure out, but I can't seem to find how I can extract each and every Lat and Lng value.

If I'm Taking a wrong approach by using stringify in JS to save the original array to a text file,please be free to offer a better solution.

Thank you in advance

Here is the code I have at the moment:

**PHP**

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $_POST['RoutePath'];
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

**Javascript**

```
directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
console.log(response);
varRoutePath = response.routes[0].overview_path;
console.log(varRoutePath);

xml = JSON.stringify(varRoutePath);
console.log(xml);

function fuDownloadRoute() {
    console.log("fuDownloadRoute");
    console.log(xml);

    $.post('Test.php', { RoutePath: xml },
        function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        });
}
```

Comment: You should add the URL you're querying to get the data. There might be a way to get geojson data (a standard format) and from that, you can use a library to convert to kml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your coordinates are in JavaScript object notation ([JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)) format. PHP has a function set for encoding and decoding JSON strings.

In your particular case you might use `json_decode()` as follows to first convert the text into an array, and then iterate over each coordinate pair:

```
$myjson = '[{"lat":51.101510000000005,"lng":4.948580000000001},{"lat":51.10208,"lng":4.94763},{"lat":51.102160000000005,"lng":4.94744},{"lat":51.102140000000006,"lng":4.944330000000001}]';
$coordinates = json_decode($myjson, true); // decode into associative array

foreach($coordinates as $pair) {
  echo $pair['lat'] .','. $pair['lng'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

> 51.10151,4.94858
>   51.10208,4.94763
>   51.10216,4.94744
>   51.10214,4.94433